# XPath query works with online tools but not in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I am able to get the below xpath to work against the below xml with online xpath tools but I am getting an "Expression must evaluate to a node-set." exception in .NET 4.5

xpath:

```
//*[starts-with(name(.), "childnode")[identification/text()='xyz']]
```

xml:

```xml
<rootnode>
    <childnode1234>
        <identification>xyz</identification>
    </childnode1234>
    <childnode3456>
        <identification>abc</identification>
    </childnode3456>
 </rootnode>
```

The expected result is

```
<childnode1234>
            <identification>xyz</identification>
        </childnode1234>
```

Comment: Which online tools are you using? What are they returning?

Comment: Did you copy your XPath correctly? What is the `";` at the end supposed to mean?

Comment: Please show real C# `string` - right now it contains non-escaped double-quotes...

Comment: The testers I've tried are:  http://www.xpathtester.com/test & http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html.  I am escaping the " with \".   The expected result is:  <childnode1234>
        <identification>xyz</identification>
    </childnode1234>

Answer (score 4):

**Just change:**

```
//*[starts-with(name(.), "childnode")[identification/text()='xyz']]
```

**to**:

```
//*[starts-with(name(.), "childnode")][identification/text()='xyz']
```

**I recommend to avoid untested and obviously buggy "no name" "online xpath tools"**.

Comment: @RossPatterson, Yes, there are a number of these that attract newbies -- only to find that they aren't compliant XPath implementations.

Answer (score 3):

The online implementations are too relaxed. Microsoft XPath is right: `starts-with()` evaluates to a boolean, not to a node-set. Try

```
//*[starts-with(name(.), 'childnode') and identification/text()='xyz']
```

Comment: +1 because I think `//*[x and y]` is stylistically preferable to `//*[x][y]`, even though they're equivalent.